# Python singleton class

Tags: python, firefox, singleton, selenium-rc

I'm writing a test suite for firefox 5.1 and selenium webdrive v.2 on os x 10.6 with Python
2.7.

Everything is working fine except the creation of a singleton class, which should guarantee
only one instance of firefox:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class Fire(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    def getdriver(self):
        return self.driver
    def close_(self):
        self.driver.close()
    def get(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        return self.driver.page_source

f  = Fire()
f.close_()
```

at this point if I call `f=Fire()`  again nothing happens. No new instance will be created.
My question is why do I see that behavior?
How I do that right?

My second question, if I type:

```
isinstance(f, Fire)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

This is strange to me ... from my understanding it should return `True`

A final question:

when I have a singleton class I should be able to do:

```
f = Fire()
f2 = Fire()
f2.get('http://www.google.com')
up to here works, but if I say
f.close_()//then
URLError: urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I can't understand this.

Answer (score 7):

Your decorator seems to work OK for me as far as creating a single instance of a class, so I don't see your issue #1. It isn't doing quite what you think it is: each time you use the decorator there's a fresh `instances` dictionary, and there's only ever one item in it, so there's not actually any reason to use a dictionary there -- you need a mutable container so you can modify it, but I'd use a list, or, in Python 3, perhaps a `nonlocal` variable. However, it does perform its intended function of making sure there's only one instance of the decorated class.

If you're asking why you can't create a new instance of the object after closing it, well, you didn't write any code to allow another instance to be created in that situation, and Python is incapable of guessing that you want that to happen. A singleton means there is only ever a single instance of the class. You have created that instance; you *can't* create another.

As for #2, your `@singleton` decorator returns a function, which instantiates (or returns a previously-created instance) of the class. Therefore `Fire` is a function, not a class, once decorated, which is why your `isinstance()` doesn't work.

The most straightforward approach to singletons, in my opinion, is to put the smarts in a class rather than in a decorator, then inherit from that class. This even makes sense from an inheritance point of view, since a singleton is a kind of object.

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

class Fire(Singleton):
     pass

f1 = Fire()
f2 = Fire()

f1 is f2              # True
isinstance(f1, Fire)  # True
```

If you still want to do it with a decorator, the simplest approach there would be to create an intermediate class in the decorator and return that:

```
def singleton(D):

    class C(D):
        _instance = None
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            if not cls._instance:
                cls._instance = D.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            return cls._instance

    C.__name__ = D.__name__

    return C

@singleton
class Fire(object):
    pass
```

You could inject the desired behavior into the existing class object, but this is, in my opinion, needlessly complex, as it requires (in Python 2.x) creating a method wrapper, and you also have to deal with the situation in which the class being decorated already has a `__new__()` method yourself.

You might think that you could write a `__del__()` method to allow a new singleton to be created when there are no references to the existing instance. This won't work because there is always a class-internal reference to the instance (e.g., `Fire._instance`) so `__del__()` is never called. Once you have a singleton, it's there to stay. If you want a new singleton after you close the old one, *you probably don't actually want a singleton* but rather something else. A [context manager](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) might be a possibility.

A "singleton" that can be re-instantiated under certain circumstances would be, to me, really weird and unexpected behavior, and I would advise against it. Still, if that's what you really want, you could do `self.__class__._instance = None` in your `close_()` method. Or you could write a separate method to do this. It looks ugly, which is fitting because it *is* ugly.  :-)

I think your third question also arises from the fact that you expect the singleton to somehow go away after you call `close_()` on it, when you have not programmed that behavior.

Comment: I suspect him being dutch, where `hier` means `here` in English.

Comment: Aren't the Dutch born with knowledge of Python?  :-)

Comment: Updated again since I think I better understand the question now after some edits.

Comment: Aren't the Dutch born with knowledge of Python? :-) You mean Monty Python?:)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your use of that singleton class as a decorator. It isn't a decorator at all, so using it like one doesn't make sense.

A decorator needs to actually return the decorated object - usually a function, but in your case, the class. You're just returning a function. So obviously, when you try and use it in `isinstance`, `Fire` no longer refers to a class.

Comment: well, finally I find a general solution to use decorator for Singletone obj. Just as Daniel sugegsted, a decorator musst return the decorated object... although my first attempt was taken from [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples), which is indicated as one of the preferred way to create singletone obj.

Comment: @Danile Rosemann well, you are right, althought in the pep-318 is indicate as the preferred way to create a singletone object. [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples)